# Multiple functions wrapped in .each(function() - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, expressionengine, vivus

Trying to turn multiple functions into one .each function in jQuery, but getting blank page. Any idea what I'm missing?

This code is functioning properly:

```
    new Vivus('svg-0', {duration: 200}, function(){
        $('.svg-animation .svg-1').css( "opacity", "0");
        $('.svg-animation .illustration-1').css( "opacity", "1");
    });

    new Vivus('svg-1', {duration: 200}, function(){
        $('.svg-animation .svg-2').css( "opacity", "0");
        $('.svg-animation .illustration-2').css( "opacity", "1");
    });


    new Vivus('svg-2', {duration: 200}, function(){
        $('.svg-animation .svg-3').css( "opacity", "0");
        $('.svg-animation .illustration-3').css( "opacity", "1");
    });

    new Vivus('svg-3', {duration: 200}, function(){
        $('.svg-animation .svg-4').css( "opacity", "0");
        $('.svg-animation .illustration-4').css( "opacity", "1");
    });
```

Here's the each function I'm trying to build:

```
$('.drawings').each(function (index, value) {
    var svgs = ($(this).find('#svg-' + index));
    //console.log(svgs);

    new Vivus(svgs, {duration: 200}, function(){
        $('.svg-animation .svg-' + index).css( "opacity", "0");
        $('.svg-animation .illustration-' + index).css( "opacity", "1");
    }); 
});
```

Here's HTML if needed...the brackets are code used in ExpressionEngine:

```
<div class="svg-animation">
    <div class="drawings mac">
       <svg id="svg-{blocks:index:of:type}" class="svg svg-{blocks:index:of:type}" style="max-width: {svg_max_width}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="{svg_view_box}">
            <title>{svg_title}</title>
            {svg_code}
        </svg>
        <img class="illustration illustration-{blocks:index:of:type}" style="max-width: {svg_max_width}" src="/assets/src_assets/images/step-1-img.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    new Vivus('svg-'+i, {duration: 200}, function(){
        $('.svg-animation .svg-'+(i+1)).css( "opacity", "0");
        $('.svg-animation .illustration-'+(i+1)).css( "opacity", "1");
    });
}
```

Otherwise, based upon your markup snippet, here is a dynamic variant:

```
$('.drawings .svg').each( function() {

    var theID = $(this).attr('id').replace("svg-", "");
    var nextID = theID + 1;


    new Vivus('svg-'+theID, {duration: 200}, function(){
        $('.svg-animation .svg-'+ nextID).css( "opacity", "0");
        $('.svg-animation .illustration-'+ nextID).css( "opacity", "1");
    });

}
```

Comment: appears to work, however the amount of items may vary since this is dynamic content. What would be the best way to find each. Assuming counting all the svg ids first and then using that number to iterate through?

Comment: Is it a known vlaue? I mean, can you assign the total amount to some variable?  var somevar = [total_amount]

Comment: selectors aren't working, based on first example....`svg-'+(i+1))` and `.illustration-'+(i+1))`. If I manually add `.svg-1` and `.illustration-1` or the like, it works for that selector. Ideas?

Comment: I edited my answer adding var nextID to simpify the code.